# Maxima does not solve the system sqrt(x)=1, y=1 with the solve function

Tags: maxima

I'm trying to solve system of equations with roots in maxima, for example:

```
solve([sqrt(x) = 1, y = 1], [x,y]);
```

But maxima says that this system has no solutions. On the other hand, maxima is able to solve this equation:

```
solve([sqrt(x) = 1], [x]);
```

Can I solve systems like the above in maxima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `solve` has serious limitations. The add-on function `to_poly_solve` can solve equations which contain radicals; I don't know what its limitations are.

```
(%i2) load (to_poly_solve);
(%o2) /usr/local/share/maxima/5.40.0/share/to_poly_solve/to_poly_solve.mac
(%i3) to_poly_solve ([sqrt(x) = 1, y = 1], [x,y]);
(%o3)                       %union([x = 1, y = 1])
```

`%union` means a union of solutions. Since there is only one solution found, `%union` could be simplified away; its presence is perhaps a little inconvenient, but not incorrect.

Comment: Thanks :) Wondering why %union is used instead of a set or a list. What kind of functionality provides %union? I'm now using `args(%union([x = 1, y = 1]))` so that it becomes a list, and I can loop over it.

Comment: Well, `%union` is a way to represent multiple solutions. If there is only one solution, then, I guess, it is not necessary. But I suspect it is put there anyway for uniformity.